# Angular 2..4 *ngIF compound condition Is there a syntax for and/or?

Tags: angular

I did see somewhere that something like **::** was valid for ***ngIf** in another Stack Overflow question, but I think that related to AngularJS. I can't recall seeing any mention in the angular.io docs of something like && or || being valid in Angular 2..4 template syntax.
If it is squirrelled away somewhere, can someone point me to the relevant section, as my Google kung fu has eluded me on this one.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? Documentation for `ngIf` tells me that it contains an *expression* and if you go to the chapter Fundamentals -> Templates -> Template Syntax you can read what exactly is an expression.

Comment: @Sulthan - Well I've gone there before. And just followed your instructions and I must be blind, because I seen no mention of and/or. Can you tell me specifically what  search term I should use inside Template Syntax?

Comment: *"You write these template expressions in a language that looks like JavaScript"*. The wording is confusing but the truth is that the basics haven't changed from angular 1. Expressions are still javascript and operators like `&&` and `||` are allowed.

Comment: Ah ok thanks.. And the :: hasn't carried over from AngularJS into Angular?

Comment: If my memory doesn't fail me, :: is used in AngularJS for one time binding and not instead of && or ||. And as far as I know both && and || can be used in Angular templates. Could you explain what is the issue ? (this is a just a question out of curiosity)

Comment: It's odd I was going to use logical operators in *ngif the other day and VSCode was highlighting && in red - so I thought it was an error, then went off in search of Angular docs...

Comment: Ah... The VSCode, me too at first was surprised, used WebStorm just to check (their editor is much better for that) and was reassured.